# Ruby on Rails: how to pass JSON to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, security

I have a JavaScript snippet in my Ruby on Rails application that talks to a remote server and passes it a JSON composed of an array of dictionaries containing things like SKU, price, etc.

It's simple to generate in Ruby:

```
@items = @order.line_items.map do |item|
  {
    sku: item.variant.sku,
    price: item.variant.price
    quantity: item.quantity
    currency: current_user.currency
  }
end
```

However, when I insert it in JavaScript -- it doesn't work.

```
{        
  items: "<%= @items %>"
}
```

The problem I think is that the entities are escaped. If I use alert to inspect the returned value, I can see all the entities like quotation marks are escaped.

Other places where I interpolate values directly seem to work fine. For example:

```
invoice_number: "<%= @order.id %>"
```

Others have had this problem, but none of the solutions appear to work in this case. I've tried `raw`, `html_safe`, etc.

I must be missing something.  What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are three problems.**

**First**, you don't need `""` around `<%= @items %>`.

**Second**, `<%= @items %>` inserts `@items.to_s`, but `{"key" => 12}.to_s` equals `'{"key"=>12}'`, which is not a valid JSON.

**Third**, you need `html_safe` to make Rails to not escape special characters.

**You get:**

```
items: <%= @items.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks Danil but this doesn't work.  JS gives me a syntax error in the console related to a missing close parenthesis.  (??)  It's frustrating because I can hand code with dummy values and get it to work, but can't get the values to insert from ruby.  It really wants to represent those quotes as entities.

Comment: items: "[{&quot;sku&quot;=&gt;&quot;1068R-FR&quot;, &quot;price&quot;=&gt;#&lt;BigDecimal:7f8cede8d498,&#39;0.1901E2&#39;,18(27)&gt;, &quot;quantity&quot;=&gt;1, &quot;currency&quot;=&gt;&quot;EUR&quot;}]"
                                     }

Comment: (That's what the original code puts into the page source).  I've tried several different approaches but it always represents quotes as entities.  If I hand code, it works great, but of course that won't work irl.  There must be a way to get a JSON object out of Ruby and into JS?  Thanks Danil for any suggestions!

Comment: Hang on...you were right.  When I printed out my array onto the rails console, I got this: [{"sku"=>"1068R-FR", "price"=>#<BigDecimal:7f8cf5157af0,'0.1901E2',18(27)>, "quantity"=>1, "currency"=>"EUR"}].  When I hand coded that big decimal to "10" AND used your suggestion, those entity tags went away and I got this in the source: [{"sku":"1068R-FR","price":"10","quantity":1,"currency":"EUR"}].  Yay!

Comment: Now the problem is to get the BigDecimal to show up correctly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Works.  You rock.  Of course I will upvote and accept.  You are a lifesaver.

Comment: Remember that `html_safe` doesn't make a string safe to insert into a page, it just tells Rails that you know it's already safe so Rails won't do anything to prevent XSS attacks. So don't use `html_safe` if there's any possibility that an `item` contains any user input, because if it does, it's not HTML safe.